# Assets count conditional

Tags: assets

I have a simple question about Assets. I want to output some HTML around a set of image IF there is more than one image. If there is just one image I would output different HTML. I know how to do this easily within EE's Assets but not sure how to do it in Craft's Assets.

In EE I would use something like:

```
{if photo:total_files > "1"} <!-- if there is more than one photo show a slideshow -->
<ul class="slider">
    <img scr="">
</ul>

{if:else} <!-- if its just one photo show it... -->
    <img scr="" class="single">
{/if}
```

I think I could target the first image but not sure how to construct the full conditional.

```
{% if entry.photos | length %}

{% set image = entry.assetFieldHandle.first() %}
<img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" width="{{ image.getWidth() }}" height="{{ image.getHeight() }}">

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're close!

```
{% set numberOfPhotos = entry.photos|length %}

{% if numberOfPhotos > 1 %}
  {# more than one #}
{% elseif numberOfPhotos == 1 %}
  {# exactly one #}
{% else %}
  {# no photos (always handle this case...) #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Marion! This was a huge help. I almost had things working using a {{ loop.index }} conditional but yours works much better. Thanks again! Greatly appreciate the advice.